# im trying to face detection using google vision but vivo v3max not detect frame in bitmap

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-detection, google-vision

I have created face swap functionality in our app but some devices such as Vivo v3max can't detect frame while using google vision face detector please tell me how to solve this problem.

all other devices are working properly with this API except Vivo v3max running on android 5.1.1.

```
08-26 12:39:08.994 7186-7227/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
        at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:733)
        at jz.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):79)
        at jq.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):67)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):83)
        at cp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):160)
        at j.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzm.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbd.zzf(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzz$zzb.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
        at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:733) 
        at jz.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):79) 
        at jq.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):67) 
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):83) 
        at cp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):160) 
        at j.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@18719034@18.7.19 (020408-262610125):4) 
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzb.zza(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzm.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbd.zzf(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzz$zzb.run(Unknown Source) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 23 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```